# How to implement a short version of the same contact form in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, mail-form

I'm not sure if I worded that title correctly, but I want to have a short version of my contact form on my index page. The problem is that the shorter version is still expecting the same validations as the long version, and it redirects to the contacts/new path when there are errors. How would I handle a situation like this; because this short contact form requires different behavior than the long version, would I have to somehow make a different contact form all together? Any help or suggestions on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

**Short**:
This is in the root page

```
    <%= simple_form_for @contact, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-3">
          <%= f.label :firstName, 'Name' %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <%= f.input_field :firstName, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Name" %><br/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-3">
          <%= f.label :email, 'Email' %><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Email" %><br/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-3">
          <%= f.label :phoneNumber, 'Phone' %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <%= f.input_field :phoneNumber, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Phone" %><br/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
          <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit Request', :class=> "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

**Model**

```
    class Contact < MailForm::Base
  validates_presence_of :firstName, :lastName, :email, :budget, :message => "Can't Be Blank"

  attribute :firstName
  validates_format_of :firstName, :with => /\A([a-z]|[A-Z])/i

  attribute :lastName
  validates_format_of :lastName, :with => /\A([a-z]|[A-Z])/i

  attribute :company
  validates_format_of :company, :with => /\A([a-z]|[A-Z])/i,
                                :allow_blank => true

  attribute :email
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i,
                              :message => "Invalid Format"

  attribute :phoneNumber
  validates_format_of :phoneNumber, :with => /\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/i,
                                    :allow_blank => true,
                                    :length => { :minimum => 10, :maximum => 31 },
                                    :message => "Invalid Format"

  attribute :requestedArea, :validate => true
  validates_format_of :requestedArea, :with => /\A([a-z]|[A-Z])/i

  attribute :requestedState
  validates_format_of :requestedState, :with => /\A([a-z]|[A-Z])/i,
                                       :allow_blank => true
  attribute :requestedCity
  validates_format_of :requestedCity, :with => /\A([a-z]|[A-Z])/i,
                                      :allow_blank => true
  attribute :contactMethod
  attribute :budget, :validate => true
  attribute :numberOfRooms

  attribute :numberOfOccupants
  attribute :purpose
  attribute :pets
  attribute :petType
  attribute :numberOfPets
  attribute :arrivalDate

  attribute :departureDate
  validates_format_of :departureDate, :with => /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/i,
                                      :allow_blank => true
  def headers
    {
      :subject => "Quote Requested!",
      :to => "anthonydevenuto@gmail.com",
      :from => %(#{email})
    }
  end
end
```

**Controller**

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end
  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    # @contact.request = request
    if @contact.deliver
      flash[:notice] = 'Thank you for your request. We will contact you soon!'
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Cannot send message.'
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: close unnecessary validation undes `if` clause, `if: { condition }` so then condition is false validation will not be executed

Comment: Thanks for the response. How would I check the current url in the model? Also, in the case of an error, how would you deal with the redirect?

Comment: you should not check url or redirect, just set `attr_accessor` from controoler, and then verify it in the model. but check url and redirect do in controller

Comment: Could you show me an example? I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0):

For example  declare accessor attribute in the model, and use it when require to skip some validations.

```
class Contact < MailForm::Base
   attr_accessor :short_form

   validates_presence_of :firstName, :lastName, :email, :budget, :message => "Can't Be Blank", unless: -> { short_form }

   # etc
end
```

use it in controller like this:

```
def action
   contact = Contact.find_by_id(params[:id])

   # ... do with contact
   if params[:short_form]
       contact.short_form = true
   end

   contact.save!
end
```